# How to select specific part of html with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below html is parsed from Yahoo Finance:

```
<TABLE class="yfnc_tabledata1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <TR class="yfnc_modtitle1" style="border-top:none;">
          <td colspan="2" style="border-top:2px solid #000;">
            <small>
              <span class="yfi-module-title">Period Ending</span>
            </small>
          </td>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2014</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2013</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2012</th>
        </TR>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Total Revenue
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              4,479,648&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              3,777,068&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              3,209,782&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Cost of Revenue</td>
          <td align="right">3,160,470&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">2,656,189&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">2,284,485&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I would like to select all `html` underneath this part:

```
<TABLE class="yfnc_tabledata1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <TR class="yfnc_modtitle1" style="border-top:none;">
          <td colspan="2" style="border-top:2px solid #000;">
            <small>
              <span class="yfi-module-title">Period Ending</span>
            </small>
          </td>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2014</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2013</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2012</th>
        </TR>
```

How do I achieve this using BeautifulSoup: `select()` method? or any other alternative ways?

PS:
Please point me to the doc if you may.

Comment: That's some strange selection, since you will have a few html tags in the selection that don't have a matching pair in it. Is that what you want?

Comment: There are more tags inside the second `TABLE` tag which I get rid of. I would like to select all `html tag` except the part I mention above. @DJanssens

Comment: There's a yahoo finance python library you can use, to both save your time, and their servers.

Comment: I'm aware of Yahoo Finance library, unfortunately it doesn't related to ideal project.

Comment: @TankorSmash is right: (http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/). Using an API might save you quite some time. Related to the beautifulsoup question. I believe I still don't really see what you want to select and what not. As far as I know BeautifulSoup always works in pairs of HTML tags. So taking <h1><b>hi  from  <h1><b>hi</b><h1> is gonna be hard. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: Can you comment the link you want to parse and specify the information you need to parse please?